# Where is the "Go To Type Definition" context menu item?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

There used to be a handy little context menu item "Go To Type Definition".  When I would right-click on a variable, for instance, I could use this to go to its type definition instead of the variable definition itself.  However, this is no longer available:

[image]

If I go to "Tools > Customize > Commands", it shows that the tool *should* be in the list:

[image]

What am I missing?  That was a very convenient feature.

**UPDATE:** I realized where I used to use it.  It's available in VB:

[image]

How do I make it available in C#?

Comment: Why not click on the type and use 'goto definition' (or in VS15 'peek definition') there? It'll bring up the type definition..

Comment: @TaW I guess because it's a two stage process if you are not already on the variable declaration line.

Comment: Because I don't have the definition nearby.  All I have is somewhere the variable is being used, elsewhere in the code.

Comment: That's right. But if you use F12 (which is the current shortcut) two times it'll be faster than any right-clicking anyway.

Comment: I guess the main question now is: why doesn't the presence of that tool in the context menu configuration (as shown in my second screen shot) make it available from the actual context menu?

Comment: Let me add two more questions: What is the meaning of 'Goto declaration' and why doesn't it show up here either..??

Comment: I guess it's a per language feature. Not sure what it is about C# that makes it difficult to jump to type def, perhaps it's something to do with `var` or `dynamic`. I suppose you're stuck with the double hop for now.

Comment: @DavidG (and everyone else) thank you for your feedback, if only to serve as a sanity check :)

Comment: it's disappeared for me in vb!  I used that on a regular basis in 2013. :(

Comment: Note in VS 2017 this is now 'Go to Implementation'

Comment: in `VB` you can use `F12` key

Comment: @apc -- No, that doesn't work.  If I have a `foreach (var x in myCollection)` where `MyCollection` is a `List<Widget>`, it doesn't go to the `Widget` definition when I use "go to implementation".

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Tools` -> `Customize` -> `Commands` tab
2. Select `Context menu` radio button
3. Select `Editor Context Menu | Code Window`
4. Click `Add Command...` button
5. Select `Edit` in `Categories` list
6. Select `Go To Type...` in `Commands` list
7. Click `OK` for `Add Command` window
8. Click `Close` for `Customize` window
9. Enjoy!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately it doesn't work.  It just brings up the same interface as Ctrl + , and puts "t" in the box (to filter to just types) and then puts the name of the variable in next to it.  Since the variable isn't itself a type, it returns nothing.